# How to store multiple RGB Images in one array in C++/OpenCv

Tags: c++, arrays, image, opencv

Supoose I have 10 RGB Images with me. How to store all the images in a single array.

Like if we have one RGB Image then we can make

```
  Mat img = imread("test.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
  Mat arr = Mat zeros(row, col, CV_32FC1);
  arr  = img.clone();
```

In this way we can read the Image. BUt I want to read 10 images say and want to store in the same aaray "**arr**". Is it possible to do it. If so, how??

Comment: Your second loc does not compile, but is also superfluous in general. You also do not need to clone in the third line. After the first line you can just work with img. And you can read multiple images into a std::vector<cv::Mat> for example. But I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: do you want one big image containing all smaller images (like tiles)?

Comment: Or possibly averaged together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to store 10 images into a single array as Dobi indicates, you can use `std::vector<cv::Mat>`

like

`std::vector<cv::Mat> Vec();`

then

`Vec.push_back(img);`

Comment: gilbert, if you initialize it with 10 and do a push_back() you got 11 elements, the 1st 10 empty. so - start with an empty vector for push_back or use vec[i] to assign it in the Vec(10) case.

Comment: @berak That's true. It should not be initialised in this way. Thx

Comment: we can remove the comments now ?

Comment: @berak Whatever, leave it could be beneficial :)

Answer (score 0):

cv::Mat allows you to push_back a bit like the std::vector, so you can simply do this:

```
   //read a few images
   cv::Mat img1 = imread("test1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
   cv::Mat img2= imread("test2.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

   //make sure same size
   CV_Assert(img2.size() == img1.size()); 

   //combine into a new image
   cv::Mat im1im2; 
   im1im2.push_back(img1);
   im1im2.push_back(img2);
```

Of course you can do in a loop also.

Cheers